# C++ Url Routing (and possible parsing)

Tags: api, boost, boost-beast, beast

I start an api server with Boost Beast.
I use the async http server.
My goal is to do the same things as Express.js
For now I route like this :

```
if(req.method() == http::verb::post)
    {
        if(req.target() == "/mypath")
        {
                                //do stuff
        }
else
    if(req.method() == http::verb::get)
    {
        if(req.target() == "/another/path")
        {
               //do stuff
         }
```

I would like to route like this :
`route.get("/mypath", callback) ;`

But how do that?

Comment: How about an unordered_map of type string and pointers to your callbacks?

Comment: Like this : `void get(const std::string& resource, std::function<void(http::request_parser<http::empty_body>)> callback); `?

Comment: I don't know, I had something slightly different in mind. Try that and let me know.